# Onde encontro DOMPDF v.5

Tags: dompdf

Só estou achando a versão 6 no GitHub, mas quero usar a versão 5 que tenha os seguintes arquivos:

```
dompdf/
|--include/
|--lib/
|--changelog.txt
|--docblox.dist.xml
|--dompdf.php
|--dompdf_config.custom.inc.php
|--dompdf_config.inc.php
|--LICENSE.LGPL
|--load_font.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Github os repositórios podem ter versões registadas. Ou seja, o autor decide assiciar um commit (um momento no desenvolvimento) como versão xxx. Assim usando essas tags pode ir-se ao histórico do repositório buscar versões anteriores.

Carregando aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

vais dar a este ecrã onde podes escolher a versão que queres e fazer download e ver a documentação dessa versão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigada achei o que queria!